# Linked list - insert before method causes the linked list to continue forever

Tags: java, eclipse, function, methods, linked-list

When I call this insert before method, it does what it is supposed to do at first, but then it causes the linked list to keep going on and on forever until i click stop (with system out print). I can't find where it goes wrong in this method

```
private boolean insertBefore(Node aNode, Node beforeNode)
    {
        Node currentNode;
        Node prevNode;
        //aNode= new Node();

        currentNode = this.getHead();

        while(currentNode!=null && currentNode.getNext()!=aNode)
        {

            if(currentNode == beforeNode)
                {
                    prevNode = this.getPrevious(beforeNode);
                    prevNode.setNext(aNode);
                    aNode.setNext(beforeNode);
                    //aNode.setNext(currentNode);
                    return true;
                }

            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        currentNode.setNext(beforeNode);

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: How is this question different from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023562/linked-list-cant-figure-out-why-this-insert-before-method-is-causing-the-link?

Comment: I initially pasted the wrong method into that one, everyone who commented was commenting on another method all together

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler than the code specified above, given you have a doubly-linked list there is no need to loop over all the elements:

```
private boolean insertBefore(Node aNode, Node beforeNode) {
    if(beforeNode.getPrevious() != null) {
        beforeNode.getPrevious().setNext(aNode);
        aNode.setPrevious(beforeNode);
    } else {
        head = aNode;
    }
    aNode.setNext(beforeNode);
    beforeNode.setPrevious(aNode);
}
```

If the `beforeNode` is at the head of the list, your new node becomes the head.

Otherwise, there is a node behind your `beforeNode`. This must now point at your new node.

Either way, your new node's next pointer points at the `beforeNode` node.

Comment: that still makes it go on forever

Comment: @user2997963 To "go on forever" the linked-list nodes must contain a circular reference. The code above *should* prevent that from happening.

Comment: Just saw the new one, there is no "setPrevious" method unfortunately

Comment: @user2997963 If you have the concept of *both* a next and a previous node (i.e. it is a doubly-linked-list), you must support `setPrevious()`. Otherwise, you need to use a loop (like in your original question) and you should remove the `getPrevious()` method